# Polar form of a complex number..

Tags: linear-algebra

$z^{3}=(\sqrt{3}+i)$

My attempt:

$|z| = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3}^{2}+1^{2}}$

$|z| = 2^{1/3}$

$\tan^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3}) = .523598775$ or exact form $\pi/6$

so, I get $2^{1/3}(\cos(\pi/6)+ i \sin(\pi/6))$

This is not one of the listed correct answers. Also from my understanding since the complex number is in the first quadrant I do not need to add pi. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to divide the angle by $3$ to reflect the cube root

Comment: Thank you for the edit and for your comment. Will do questions like that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\sqrt{3}+i= 2\left(\sqrt{3}/2+i/2 \right) = 2\left(\cos \pi/6 + i \sin \pi/6\right)$, so your equation is
$$z^3 = 2\left(\cos \pi/6 + i\sin \pi/6\right).$$
Then 
$$z = \sqrt[3]{2}\left(\cos \frac{\pi/6+2k\pi}{3} +i\sin \frac{\pi/6+2k\pi}{3}\right), \quad k=0,1,2. $$

Comment: Thank you! I see the logic now.

Comment: Wait a second, wouldn't it be cos$(\pi/6*3)+i$sin$(\pi/6*3)$ where are you getting  $\cos \frac{\pi/6+2k\pi}{3}$ from?

Comment: where are you getting k from?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/nth-roots-of-complex-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

By De Moivre's Theorem: $$z^n=r^n(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))$$
$$\to z^3=r^3(\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)) $$

You've calculated $r=\sqrt[3]{2}$ correctly

However, you have calculated $3\theta$ instead of $\theta $
Now, your value of $3\theta=\frac\pi6$ is only *partially* correct. It should be $3\theta=\frac\pi6+2k\pi=\frac{12k+1}{2}\pi, k\in \Bbb Z$. 
This leads to $\theta=\frac{12k+1}{6}\pi$

So we have $$z=\sqrt[3]{2}(\cos[\frac{12k+1}{6}\pi]+i\sin [\frac{12k+1}{6}\pi]), k\in \Bbb Z$$

Use k=0,1,-1,2 etc to find the solutions you require.